# 403, If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required

Tags: python, gdata, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-apps-marketplace

Background Info

I am Using `python` `gdata` `spreadsheet-api` with `OAuth2.0` and `certificate credentials` to access data in a google apps domain

I am trying to insert a row into a spreadsheet using

```
spreadSheetClient = SpreadsheetsClient()
# Certificate Authentication  ....
spreadSheetClient.add_list_entry(list_entry=list_entry, spreadsheet_key=spreadSheetKey,
                                                     worksheet_id=workSheetId)
```

where `list_entry` is an instance of `gdata.spreadsheets.data.ListEntry` and `spreadsheetKey` and `worksheetId` are instances of `str`

I am getting the following error

```
  File "/home/gautam/Projects/osflow/build/runtime/gdata/spreadsheets/client.py", line 450, in update_cell
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/gautam/Projects/osflow/build/runtime/gdata/client.py", line 730, in update
    desired_class=entry.__class__, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gautam/Projects/osflow/build/runtime/gdata/client.py", line 319, in request
    RequestError)
RequestError: Server responded with: 403, If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

ListFeed appends rows, rather than inserts them and columns want a column header (I think the header is required).

For an example of how to use list feed, look at http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/list/ListDemo.java

I have not used list feed that often, but it feels very much like using SQL, where you filter/append etc. I tend to use Cell Feed instead.

Comment: So Is there a way to use this to insert the header (first row ) ?

Comment: CellFeed will let you add a header row. If I remember correctly, CellFeed is the only way this can be done with GData style spreadsheet API. Google-Apps-Script can update and insert rows.