# Getting "If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required" errors when batch deleting contacts

Tags: python, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using the `gdata` Python library to do batched deletes of contacts, and I just get the "If-Match or If-None-Match header or entry etag attribute required" error.

I think the problem started when I had to enable the Contacts API in the console (which until a few days ago wasn't required? *).

**EDIT**:

It's actually failing for both updating and deleting operations. Batched insert works fine.

Tried specifying the `If-Match` header, but it's still failing:

```
custom_headers = atom.client.CustomHeaders(**{'If-Match': '*'})
request_feed = gdata.contacts.data.ContactsFeed()
request_feed.AddDelete(entry=contact, batch_id_string='delete')
response_feed = self.gd_client.ExecuteBatch(
        request_feed,
        'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch',
        custom_headers=custom_headers
)
```

Also created a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=700&thanks=700&ts=1401265148) on the project page, but I doubt it will get any attention there.

**EDIT 2:**

Using the `Batch` method with `force=True` (which just adds the `If-Match: *` header) is the same result.

```
response_feed = self.gd_client.Batch(
    request_feed,
    uri='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch',
    force=True
)
```

* Can someone verify this? I never had to enable it in the console before and my app was able to use the Contacts API without problem, and I believe it wasn't even available before. I was surprised to see it yesterday.

Comment: iam also facing same issue, any updates about this issue

Comment: Without knowing the details of the gdata library, shouldn't you pass the custom_headers instance to the request somehow? Or maybe install it on `gd_client`? I doubt it will add the headers just by creating a CustomHeaders instance.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch. That was a typo. Edited.

Comment: Does this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989257/if-match-or-if-none-match-header-or-entry-etag-attribute-required-error-when-t

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270565/403-if-match-or-if-none-match-header-or-entry-etag-attribute-required

Comment: The PHP guy got his working by adding the `If-Match` header (which still fails in my case). The other one is for spreadsheets and only seems to be tangentially related. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying answer from the Google code ticket.

Basically, you need to patch the client's `Post` method to modify the request feed slightly. Here's one way to do it without directly modifying the library source:

```
def patched_post(client, entry, uri, auth_token=None, converter=None, desired_class=None, **kwargs):
    if converter is None and desired_class is None:
        desired_class = entry.__class__
    http_request = atom.http_core.HttpRequest()
    entry_string = entry.to_string(gdata.client.get_xml_version(client.api_version))
    entry_string = entry_string.replace('ns1', 'gd')  # where the magic happens
    http_request.add_body_part(
        entry_string,
        'application/atom+xml')
    return client.request(method='POST', uri=uri, auth_token=auth_token,
                          http_request=http_request, converter=converter,
                          desired_class=desired_class, **kwargs)

# when it comes time to do a batched delete/update,
# instead of calling client.ExecuteBatch, instead directly call patched_post
patched_post(client_instance, entry_feed, 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/batch')
```

Answer (score 1):

The ticket referenced in the original post has some updated information and a temporary work around that allows batch deletes to succeed. So far it's working for me!

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=700

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the etag attribute to get around it. This works in the batch request payload:

```
  <entry   gd:etag="*"  >
     <batch:id>delete</batch:id>
     <batch:operation type="delete"/>
     <id> urlAsId </id>
  </entry>
```